# Hibernate left join between independent tables - org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException Path expected for join

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have some tables listed in persistence.xml as:

```
<persistence-unit name="myEntityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <class>com.myPackage.someTable</class>
   <class>com.myPackage.tableOne</class>
   <class>com.myPackage.tableTwo</class>
   <class>com.myPackage.tableThree</class>
   <class>com.myPackage.tableThreePK</class>
   <class>com.myPackage.tableFour</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Thus the classes are independent of each other. No relationships defined between them.

I have a sql query as below:

```
select s.* from someTable s 
join tableOne O on s.col1 = O.col1 
join tableTwo T on s.col2 = T.col2 
join tableThree Th on s.col3 = Th.col3 and s.col4 = Th.col4 
left join tableFour f on s.col6 = F.col6 
where s.col5 = 'abc'
```

How to write this query in hibernate for above scenario:

```
select s.* from someTable s 
join tableOne O  
join tableTwo T  
join tableThree Th 
left join tableFour f 
where s.col5 = :col5 
and s.col1 = O.col1 
and s.col2 = T.col2 
and s.col3 = Th.pk.col3 and s.col4 = Th.col4 
and s.col6 = F.col6 

myQuery.setParameter("col5", "abc");
```

Above query doesn't work and gives

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

What is the issue ?
What am I missing ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HQL doesn't support left joins without associations between entities. You'll have to use a SQL query to do that.

Side note: `select s.*` isn't valid HQL. `select s` is.

Comment: Thanks... Does hibernate allow simple joins without associations between entities ? Because even the below query is not working (only removed the "left" keyword from the query in my question): select s from someTable s join tableOne O join tableTwo T join tableThree Th join tableFour f where s.col5 = :col5  and s.col1 = O.col1  and s.col2 = T.col2  and s.col3 = Th.pk.col3 and s.col4 = Th.col4  and s.col6 = F.col6

Comment: No. You must make a join using the where clause: select s from SomeTable s, TableOne O, ... where s.col1 = O.col1 ...

Comment: In that case I think, I will have to define associations between all classes.. because the query with both "where clause for normal joins" and "single left join for the last table" is not possible... or is it ?

Comment: No, it isn't. I don't see the point of using Hibernate without using associations between entities. That's the whole point of an ORM. The other option is to use a SQL query rather than a HQL query.